# Discrete subgroups of Lie groups other than Lattices

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory

I know a lattice is a discrete group of $G$ which is of finite covolume. I am just curious to know examples of discrete subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ or in particular $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ other than lattices which are important in literature. I am also curious to know whether there are some famous (i.e studied rigorously in many contexts)discrete subgroups of $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$ in literature other than lattices?

Comment: In $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ for example a subgroup consisting of matrices of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1& \mathbb{Z}\\\
0& 1
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$

Comment: Ok. I am just bit curious I was looking at Kleinian groups i.e discrete subgroups of $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$. I am bit curious to know whether there are some important Kleinian groups in literature other than lattices?

Comment: Read here
 [Why is this discrete subgroup of $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$
 not Kleinian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2756644)

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing out here. But what I am asking is there some discrete subgroups of $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ or $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$ other than lattices which has been studied rigorously. As for example lattices are important example, my question is what are the importnant examples of discrete subgroups in $SL_2(\mathbb{R}$ or $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$ which are not lattices.

Comment: I think it would be properly refined if you clarified your question at least by adding to it everything you noted in the comments. I am not an expert on discrete subgroups of Lie groups, I just studied these questions once. There is a good book, perhaps you have seen it: Raghunatan, Discrete subgroups of Lie groups. Read also [Michael Kapovich](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/EPR/birs-problem-list.pdf).

Comment: Sure I am clarifying it.

Comment: One example is the derived subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$.